# Computing last two digits of $27^{2018}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

For abstract algebra I have to find the last two digits of $27^{2018}$, without the use of a calculator, and as a hint it says you should work in $\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$.

I thought breaking up the problem into $\mod(100)$ arguments. Thus:
$27^{2}=729\equiv 29 \mod (100)$, and

$27^{4}=(27^{2})^{2} \equiv 29^{2}=861\equiv 61 \mod (100)$ and

$27^{8}=(27^{4})^{2} \equiv 61^{2}=3421 \equiv 21 \mod(100)$ and so on until I would find something that repeated itself. But I've done quite some terms no and I've not seen any iteration yet. So I'm thinking this is the wrong way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you taking powers of $27$ if you want a power of $2$?

Comment: Sorry, typo! edited the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\phi(100)=40$, so we can reduce the exponent mod $40$:
$$
27^{2018}\equiv27^{18}\pmod{100}
$$
Then we can [square and multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring):
$$
\begin{align}
27^2&\equiv29\\
27^4&\equiv41\\
27^8&\equiv81\\
27^9&\equiv87\\
27^{18}&\equiv69\pmod{100}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very clear and seems like a way faster method than I was using. Thanks.

Comment: @Mathbeginner The fastest way is probably via the Binomial Theorem, e.g. see my answer ($10$ seconds of very trivial mental arithmetic)

Comment: @BillDubuque: works nicely because $3^2\equiv-1\pmod{10}$. It may not generalize to other bases than $3$.

Comment: @Rob Indeed, but such exercises are usually *designed* to have a nice solution by hand.

Comment: Is the downvote due to a problem or question with this answer? I think the square and multiply algorithm after reducing the exponent by the totient of the modulus is a decent and fairly algorithmic approach to this type of question.

Comment: I don't see any problem.  In case you might not know, there are at least a handful of  users who don't like such questions, so perhaps they may use such votes to try to discourage folks who answer them (I occasionally get such votes too).

Comment: @BillDubuque: I understand that, but those are usually for questions with no effort shown, and this question shows the attempt made. Because mine was the only answer downvoted, I was thinking it might be something other than just the question.

Comment: Btw, to clarify, "such questions" above doesn't refer to general "low quality" questions but, rather, to questions on modular exponentiation. A few users have expressed opinions that most such questions should be closed as dupes of a generic "abstract dupe" thread. Further some think answering such questions is based purely on rep-hunting. As I've mentioned elsewhere, I disagree in general   (though I might agree that some specific cases are dupes).

Answer (score 2):

$27^{5} = 7 \quad (\mathrm{mod} \text{ } 100)$.

So $27^{2018} = 27^{403 \times 5 + 3} = 7^{403} \times 27^3 \quad(\mathrm{mod} \text{ } 100)$.

Now $7^4 = 1 \quad (\mathrm{mod} \text{ } 100)$.  So $27^{2018} = 7^{4 \times 100 + 3} \times 27^3 = 7^3 \times 27^3$.

And $7 \times 27 = 189 = -11 \quad (\mathrm{mod} \text{ } 100)$. So $(7 \times 27)^3 = - 11^3 = 69 \quad (\mathrm{mod} \text{ } 100)$. You get finally $$27^{2018} = 69 \quad (\mathrm{mod} \text{ } 100)$$

Comment: Do you know, without use of a calculator, that $27^{5}\equiv 7 \mod (100)$?

Comment: I think you meant $11^3$, not $33$

Comment: @Mathbeginner $27^5 = 27 \times (27^2)^2$. Now $27^2 = 729 = 29 \quad (\mathrm{mod} \text{ } 100)$. So $27^5 = 27 \times 29^2$ which you can compute by hand.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, typo, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

$\bmod 100\!:\,\ 3^{\large 3\cdot 2018}\!\equiv 9^{\large 3027}\!\equiv\underbrace{(-1\!+\!10)^{\large 3027}\!\equiv -1 +\! \overbrace{3027}^{\large \color{#c00}{7}+10j}(\color{#c00}{10})}_{\rm Binomial\ Theorem\ }\equiv -1+\color{#c00}{70}\equiv 69$

Comment: +1: nice and different approach

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Chinese remainder theorem and do the problem inside $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ separately. $27$ has order $20$ in $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$ and order 2 in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. We have $27^{2018} = 27^{18} = 19 \pmod{25}$ and $27^{2018} = 1 \pmod{4}$, so $27^{2018} = 69 \pmod{100}$.

Comment: how do you see so quickly that $27$ has order $20$ in $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $2^{10} = 1024 = 24 = -1 \pmod{25}$. Or just compute the powers of $2$ mod $25$. Since $25$ is considerably smaller than $100$, it's much easier than what you were doing.

Comment: I do see how $27$ has order $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ since $729 \equiv 1 \mod (4)$ but I still don't see how what you're saying about $2^{10}$ is related to $27$ in $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$... Sorry for the lack of insight.

Comment: You can reduce modulo $4$ (or $25$) before squaring (or doing any other arithmetic), and that's essentially why using the CRT is useful here. $27 = 3 \ne 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and $3^2 = 1$. That's exactly what it means to have order $2$. Similarly, in $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$, we have $27 = 2$. And $2^{10} = 1024$. And $1024 = 24 = -1 \ne 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$. And $2^{20} = (2^{10})^2  = (-1)^2 = 1$. That's what it means to have order $20$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\varphi(100)=40$ certainly the sequence of powers of $27$ will repeat after $40$ terms. A quick calculation shows that in fact it already repeats after $20$ terms. You could also use the Chinese remainder theorem to reduce the problem to computing $27^{2018}$ mod $25$ and mod $4$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this $\varphi$, I do reckon you mean the totiënt function, right? Do you know by hearth that $\varphi(100)=40$?

Comment: Yes, totient function $\phi(100)=\phi(25)\phi(4)=(5\times4)(2\times1)$

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

As $27=3^3,N=27^{2018}=3^{3\cdot2018}$

Using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html, $\lambda(100)=20$

As $(3,100)=1,6054\equiv14\pmod{20},$

$N\equiv3^{14}\pmod{100}$

Now $3^{14}=9^7=-(1-10)^7\equiv-1+\binom71\cdot10^1\pmod{100}$

See also: [Last 3 digits of $3^{999}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789050/last-3-digits-of-3999)
[Determine the last two digits of $3^{3^{100}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743091/determine-the-last-two-digits-of-33100)

Answer (score 1):

Working in the multiplicative group of integers modulo $100$, $(\Bbb Z /100 \Bbb Z)^\times$, you can discover all that is needed to solve the problem with elementary algebra.

If $n$ is an integer denote by $[n]$ its $\text{modulo-}100$ residue class in  ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} /100 \mathbb {Z}}$.

Exercise 1: The subset $\mathcal V = \bigr\{[20n+d]\mid n \in \Bbb Z \land d \in \{1,3,7,9\}\bigr\}$ of ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} /100 \mathbb {Z}}$ is actually a subset of $(\Bbb Z /100 \Bbb Z)^\times$, forming a subgroup with $20$ elements.

Since $[27] \in \mathcal V$, $\,27^{20} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$.

To solve $27x \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$, observe that $x$ has the form $20n +3$. Multiplying,

$\tag 1 (20 + 7)(20n+3) \equiv 60 + 40n + 21 \equiv 81 + 40n \pmod{100}$

Examining $\text{(1)}$ we determine that $x \equiv 63 \pmod{100}$.

So

$\; 27^{2018} \equiv 27^{2020} \cdot 63^{2} \equiv 63 \cdot 63 \equiv 80 + 80 + 9 \equiv 69 \pmod{100}$.